# Consultar la fecha mas alta de una tabla con query builder de Laravel

Tags: php, sql, laravel, querybuilder

Estuve buscando como y solo me aparece como hacerlo con Eloquent, pero yo quiero hacerlo con el Query Builder.

Tengo una tabla con x campos, entre ellos uno que dice Fecha Vencimiento. Lo que quiero, es que me extraiga todos los datos del registro que tenga la fecha mas alta.
Esta es la tabla de la que quiero consultar los datos de la derivación con la fecha mas alta sin importar nada mas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estuve intentando hacerlo así, pero por alguna razón me da error.

```
$data= DB::table('Derivaciones')
        ->latest('FechaVencimiento')
        ->first();
```

Bien, (Esta consulta la hago con una petición HTTPRequest, solo para aclarar, por eso no puedo mostrarles cual es el error especifico que devuelve)

Después de hacer algunas pruebas, logre que funcionara parcialmente cambiando el `first()` por un `get()` el problema es que me devuelve un array de todos los registros, ordenados por fecha, siendo el primero el registro de la fecha mas alta.

```
$data= DB::table('Derivaciones')
        ->select('FechaVencimiento')
        ->latest('FechaVencimiento')
        ->get();
```

Cuando utilizo el `first()` es cuando me arroja el error. Aun no se porque. Se supone que esa función es la que extrae el primer registro de una consulta X. Estoy usando Laravel 5.6, ¿Eso afecta de algún modo?

Comment: El problema es que hago la consulta desde un XMLHTTPrequest y pues, solo me devuelve un error, pero no me dice cual. Y se que es esa la funcion que me esta devolviendo mal los datos. ¿La consulta esta bien hecha, verdad? Y respondiendo a la pregunta, puede que si, como solo tengo datos de prueba, si hay registros con la misma fecha de vencimiento. Voy a actualizar la pregunta.

Comment: DB::table('Derivaciones')->order_by('FechaVencimiento', 'desc')->first(); prueba esto, pero en realidad no se porque obligas a hacerlo con query builder